# How to get the background color of the keyboard to make own toolbar over the keyboard?

Tags: swiftui

what is the background color of the keyboard, so that I can make my own toolbar over the keyboard? Can I get the current color in the different modes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Digital Colour Meter App(Apps installed by default on Mac)

Comment: Isn’t the keyboard transparent? Can I achieve this with the blur effect?

Comment: hm
Yea, I think you can use `.blur` for that